# Maximum password length for user accounts on Ubuntu

Tags: passwords, ubuntu, user-management, vps

I have a VPS hosted at a remote location. Obviously the host can login directly (without SSH or any keys) on this box and I want to make brute force password guessing as hard as possible for a bad admin.This leads to the question:

**What is the maximum password length for user accounts in Ubuntu?**

While questions like ["what is the max length of password on unix/linux system?"](https://superuser.com/questions/148971/what-is-the-max-length-of-password-on-unix-linux-system) claim that there is no actual limit with current hash algorithms it looks like there is still some sort of OS limitation though. It accepted my 207 character password and I was able to login again with that, but my 8192 character password cause Ubuntu to crash with the error "event not found" (whatever that means). Interesting enough, I could still login with the 8k password although I get an error each time I login.

Note, that I'm logging in with a 4K RSA SSH key so I don't care about "user friendliness" for manual logins.

Comment: I know hashing algos allow any length as stated in the answer you had linked, but I was specifically asking about the Ubuntu OS and specifically about user accounts. I did a Google search and I could find any limitations as far as I know. Just because the underlying hash algo accepts any length can I assume Ubuntu does too? So can I theoretically take the text of the whole Holy Bible and paste that as a password?

Comment: Another limitation I also discovered is that if I make the password too long, the login times out before I could finish typing it.

Comment: I've incorporated some input from your comments into the question itself so that it includes already researched information now.

Comment: Typing speed is no fixed limit since it depends in how fast one can type and if one could simply cut+paste the password in the prompt.